# Set variable to $scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDIT: Following previous answers the JS has been amended to run all the code within the http.get. I have also added the HTML.

The current page can be viewed at: http://www.kamac.co.uk/wordplay3/#/gamecontrol

I have an AngularJS app with the following code in the controller:

```
var vm = this;

$http.get('data/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.entries = data;
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.entries.length);

    $scope.selectedWord = $scope.entries[rand].word;
    $scope.selectedDefinition = $scope.entries[rand].definition;

        vm.topsecret = "TopSecret";
        vm.letter = [];

        vm.checkLetter = function(index){
    if(vm.topsecret[index] === vm.letter[index]){
        vm.result = "letter was correct"
    } else {
        vm.letter[index] = "";
        vm.result = "nope";
    }
}
```

Both parts of the code do as expected. The $http.get function reads a JSON file and sets $scope.selectedWord to a randomly chosen word.

The second part creates a number of input boxes for each letter in the word saved in vm.topsecret.

My problem is this only works if vm.topsecret is hard coded. How can I get vm.letter to equal $scope.selectedWord ?

I have tried the obvious: vm.topsecret = $scope.selectedWord but this results in an empty value.

HTML

```
<section class="spellbound container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>SpellBound</h2>
<p>Below you will see a definition of one of the words in the dictionary. Enter a correct letter and the square turns green - enter a wrong letter and it turns red.</p>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">How do you spell the word that means</div>
  <div class="panel-body">{{selectedDefinition}}</div>  
</div>

<p>Answer: {{selectedWord}}</p>

<p>VM:  <span>{{vm.topsecret}}</span>

<div ng-controller="GamecontrolController as vm">
   <input type="text" ng-model="vm.letter[$index]" ng-repeat="letter in vm.topsecret track by $index" ng-change="vm.checkLetter($index)"/>
   <p><span>{{vm.result}}</span></p>
</div>
<div>
   <a ng-click="reloadPage()"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button">Play Again</a>
   <a href="#/home" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button">Back To Menu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: your issue seems to be that you are using `vm` (ControllerAs) and `$scope` in the same controller.  you should only use one form or the other; for example, move `var vm = this;` to the top, and inside the callback, set `vm.entries` instead.

Comment: however, that being said, that won't work the way you expect either, since `$http.get` is asynchronous, and therefore `vm.topsecret = ....` will be run before the response from the server has ever returned.

Comment: vm.topsecret = $scope.selectedWord won't be calculated. You need to set in $http callback and call check letter functiojn

Comment: Adding the vm code to inside the $http callback has had an interesting effect. I am seeing a new word generated each time but it does not match the word being displayed. i.e. selectedword and vm.topsecret do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving vm.topsecret like below:

```
var vm = this;
    $http.get('data/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.entries = data;
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.entries.length);

    $scope.selectedWord = $scope.entries[rand].word;
    $scope.selectedDefinition = $scope.entries[rand].definition;
vm.topsecret = $scope.selectedWord;
});



vm.letter = [];

vm.checkLetter = function(index){
    if(vm.topsecret[index] === vm.letter[index]){
        vm.result = "letter was correct"
    } else {
        vm.letter[index] = "";
        vm.result = "nope";
    }
}
```

This is just a guess since I cannot see your HTML and how you are using vm.topsecret.